# Pdf viewer asking for password but no password is set for pdf file

Tags: android, pdf, assets

I am trying to open a pdf file from asset folder of my app.

I used this code.

```
            File pdfFile = new File("file:///android_asset/c.pdf");
            Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
            startActivity(intent);
```

No password is set for my pdf file but "OfficeSuite" is asking for password when I am trying to open.

What to do?

I tried with several files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other apps cannot open `file:///android_asset` paths from your app.

Use a `ContentProvider` to stream the PDF to the other app. [My `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider) offers an out-of-the-box solution for this. Or, copy the PDF to your internal storage and use `FileProvider`, as shown in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider). Or, copy the file to external storage and use `Uri.fromFile()` to generate a `Uri` pointing to that, though [this will work with fewer and fewer apps over time](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/10/07/runtime-permissions-files-action-send.html).